# How to implement dynamic widget routing in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm adding routing into my Flutter app and I would like to re-use some common Widgets across all of my routes.

For instance, the `AppBar` and `Drawer` instances should be defined on the top level view and the routed view should be in a contained Widget (the yellow part in the image)

**Is is supported?** currently all "Flutter Routing" references I find demonstrate replacement of the entire view => different instances of the common Widgets for every route.

[image]

```
void redirect(BuildContext context, name) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(name);
}

getCommonDrawer(context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Text('header'),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('foo'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('bar'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Screen 1"),
      ),
      drawer: getCommonDrawer(context),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                redirect(context, "/screen2");
              },
              child: new Text("screen2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Screen 2"),
      ),
      drawer: getCommonDrawer(context),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                redirect(context, "/screen1");
              },
              child: new Text("screen1"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


void main() { // 1
  runApp( // 2
    new MaterialApp( //3
      home: new Screen1(), //4
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> { //5
        '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(), //6
        '/screen2' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen2() //7
      },
    )
  );
}
```